# Three.js change the pivot point of each particle

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I'm trying to rotate each particle along its own axis of rotation rather than rotate them all along one point. I've looked at many similar questions on setting the pivot points, but I'm lost and confused to be honest.

My goal is to animate the particles as if they're falling from top to bottom, similar to [this animation](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/492344).

```js
var camera,
  scene,
  renderer,
  materials = [],
  parameters;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

var particles = [];

var confetti = {
  maxCount: 2000, //set max confetti count
  speed: 1, //set the particle animation speed
  frameInterval: 30, //the confetti animation frame interval in milliseconds
  waveThreshold: 3, //
  start: null, //call to start confetti animation (with optional timeout in milliseconds, and optional min and max random confetti count)
  stop: null, //call to stop adding confetti
  toggle: null, //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
  pause: null, //call to freeze confetti animation
  resume: null, //call to unfreeze confetti animation
  togglePause: null, //call to toggle whether the confetti animation is paused
  remove: null, //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately
  isPaused: null, //call and returns true or false depending on whether the confetti animation is paused
  isRunning: null //call and returns true or false depending on whether the animation is running
};

init();
animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 20, 900);
  camera.position.z = 100;

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  var vertices = [];
  var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  var sprite1 = textureLoader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/Rhx8t6CM/confetti1.png');
  var sprite2 = textureLoader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/Rhx8t6CM/confetti1.png');
  var sprite3 = textureLoader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/Rhx8t6CM/confetti1.png');
  var sprite4 = textureLoader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/Rhx8t6CM/confetti1.png');
  var sprite5 = textureLoader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/Rhx8t6CM/confetti1.png');

  for (var i = 0; i < confetti.maxCount; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    var y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    var z = Math.random() * 1000 - 900;
    vertices.push(x, y, z);
    //particles[i].tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
    //particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
    //particles[i].tiltAngle = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    particles.push({
      'tilt': Math.random() * 1 - 1,
      'tiltAngle': Math.random() * Math.PI
    })
  }

  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

  parameters = [
    [sprite2, 10],
    [sprite3, 9],
    [sprite1, 10],
    [sprite5, 8],
    [sprite4, 10]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
    var sprite = parameters[i][0];
    var size = parameters[i][1];
    materials[i] = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      size: size,
      map: sprite,
      blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
      depthTest: false,
      transparent: true
    });
    var particle = new THREE.Points(geometry, materials[i]);
    particle.rotation.x = Math.random() * 5;
    particle.rotation.y = Math.random() * 5;
    particle.rotation.z = Math.random() * 5;
    scene.add(particle);
  }

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setClearColor('#121212')
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  var time = Date.now() * 0.00005;
  for (var i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i++) {
    var object = scene.children[i];
    if (object instanceof THREE.Points) {
      //object.rotation.x = time * ( i < 4 ? i + 1 : ( i + 1 ) );
      //object.position.x -= time * ( i < 4 ? i + 1 : -( i + 1 ) );
      object.position.y -= 1;
      object.position.x += particles[i]['tilt'] / 3;
      object.rotation.y += .001;
      //object.rotation.x += time * particles[i]['tiltAngle'];
    }
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Such animation with `THREE.Points()` needs pretty advanced knowledge of coding shaders, as you can't rotate points like that, but you can draw something on their "planes", imitating movements of rectangles.

Comment: @prisoner849 Does that mean, I won’t be able do it?

Comment: I didn't say that :) Instead of points you can use the same amount of usual meshes of planes, animating each of them at js side. Or you can create it with instancing of a plane, animating them in shaders. You can do it the way with points, that I mentioned in my first comment, though there is no simple way to achieve the desired result.